# Why does getBoundingClientRect only work locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bounding-box

Consider the follow HTML ([JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/husLqtpk/2)):

```
<div id="a" class="box">cat</div>
<div id="b" class="box rotate">cat</div>
<div id="c" class="box"><div class="rotate">cat</div></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.box    { font-size:500%; }
.rotate { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
```

Measuring the width and height of element `id=a` using `.getBoundingClientRect()`

```
$(a)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
$(a)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height
```

gives the dimensions of `(320,91)`. Measuring the same thing on element `id=b` gives the transposed dimensions `(91,320)`. Wonderful.

However, when I try to measure element `id=c` which simply nests the rotation inside an inner div, I get the originally dimensions `(320,91)`! Shouldn't the bounding boxes for `b` and `c` be the same?

If not, how can I get the bounding box of `c` to report correctly?

---

If relevant, I'm using Chromium, Version 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 12.04 (281580) (64-bit).

Comment: `$(a)[0].getBoundingClientRect()` is a really roundabout way of writing `a.getBoundingClientRect()`. If you're going to rely on the automatic globals, you may as well use 'em. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the tip! This was my attempt at a minimal working example from a larger project I'm working on. I'm well-versed in web-design and I often rely on JQuery to lift things that I'm learning can be done with less verbosity.

Comment: @Hooked: In this case, the jQuery version would be `$("#a")[0].getBoundingClientRect();` I just can't bring myself to rely on those automatic globals. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the rotated bit within `c` extends out of `c`, without changing its size. This should make it a bit clearer:

```js
var bbox_a = document.getElementById("a").getBoundingClientRect();
snippet.log("a: " + bbox_a.width + "x" + bbox_a.height);

var bbox_b = document.getElementById("b").getBoundingClientRect();
snippet.log("b: " + bbox_b.width + "x" + bbox_b.height);

var bbox_c = document.getElementById("c").getBoundingClientRect();
snippet.log("c: " + bbox_c.width + "x" + bbox_c.height);
```

```css
.box {
    font-size:500%;
}
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
#a {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#b {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#c {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#c .rotate {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="box">cat</div>
<div id="b" class="box rotate">cat</div>
<div id="c" class="box">
    <div class="rotate">cat</div>
</div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

*(I removed the reliance on automatic globals `a`, `b`, and `c` above. It just makes me jittery to rely on automatic globals, they're so easily shadowed.)*

BTW, you can visualize things like this using Chromium's dev tools: Right-click the element and choose "Inspect element", and it'll open the Elements panel in the dev tools. At that point, when your cursor is over the markup for the element in the Element's panel, dev tools will highlight that element (including its bounding box) on the page.

Comment: Alright, I see how the green box is what "c" is reporting as. How then, can I get the "effective" bounding box of c?

Comment: @Hooked: I just updated the answer to show the rotated bit within `c` more clearly. Re your question above, the only thing that comes to mind is to do a union of `#c`'s box and `#c .rotate`'s box (but my transform-fu is weak).

Comment: So you are suggesting a recursive descent into all the child objects to find the union? I think I could do that -- I guess I was thinking that this might have been something built-in already.

Comment: @Hooked: If there is, I don't know of it -- but that doesn't mean it doesn't, at all, this is an area I'm relatively weak in. I would expect MDN's pages on `getBoundingClientRect` and `getClientRects` to refer to it if there were something giving you what you're looking for, but I don't see it. Fundamentally, `c`'s bounding rectangle is what you're getting from `getBoundingClientRect`, it's just (again) that the rotated stuff within it extends *outside* `c`.